# How to re-initialize an Android Room database for a UI test

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-room

I have an Android app with a Room database. In my UI test, the Room database should be re-initialized at the beginning.

The tables cannot simply be deleted inside of Room because the Room.databaseBuilder has a callback. The callback initializes data in the tables.

```
    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            xxxDatabase.class,
            xxxDatabaseHelper.DB_NAME)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .addCallback(new xxxCallback(context)) <-- initialize db data
            .build();
```

When I drop all tables, I expect that Room thinks it's a new install and re-initializes the db. However, I get an exception that Room can't write to a read-only db.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    targetContext.deleteDatabase(RoosterDatabaseHelper.DB_NAME);
}
```

Exception:

```
 (1032) statement aborts at 78: [INSERT OR ABORT INTO `resource_type`(`id`,`name`,`precursor_resource_type_id`,`precursor_unit_type_id`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)] attempt to write a readonly database
04
```

How is the Room database reset for a UI test?

Comment: Can you use `Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder` instead?

Comment: The data has to be persisted long-term in the device. The app is completely contained on the device without a cloud backend.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought this was for your tests.

Answer (score 0):

A better method I learned for testing database is to create a ServiceLocator class like this

```
public class ServiceLocators {
    private static ServiceLocators instance;
    private static xxDatabase sDatabaseClass;

    private ServiceLocators() {
    }

    public static ServiceLocators getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ServiceLocators();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static xxDatabase getDatabaseClass(Context context) {
        if (sDatabaseClass != null) {
            return sDatabaseClass;
        } else {
            return createDatabase(context);
        }
    }

    public static void setDatabaseClass(xxDatabase databaseClass) {
        ServiceLocators.sDatabaseClass = databaseClass;
    }

    public static void resetRepository() {
        sDatabaseClass.clearAllTables();
        sDatabaseClass.close();
    }

    private static xxDatabase createDatabase(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.getApplicationContext(),
                xxDatabase.class,
                "database_name.db"
        ).build();
    }
}
```

then in your code, you call the db like this

```
ServiceLocators.getInstance().getDatabaseClass(context)
```

in your test classes, create setUp method in which you simply swap the implementation of the original database

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    xxDatabase database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, xxDatabase.class)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build();

    ServiceLocators.setDatabaseClass(database);
}
```

and teardown method to clean up the database tables

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    ServiceLocators.resetRepository();
}
```